# May I have a hint for this gcd problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, mersenne-numbers

I am trying to prove the following:

> $$(2^a - 1, 2^b - 1) = 2^{(a,b)} - 1 \ \ \ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{N} $$
>   Where:
>   $$ (a,b) := \gcd(a,b) $$

So far I have tried dividing $2^a-1$ by $2^b-1$ to see if there was anyway to get the remainder, and user the remainder to help inductively show what the $gcd$ tends toward, but all I could do through algebraic manipulation was a pathetic:

$$ \frac{2^a-1}{2^b-1} = \frac{2^a}{2^b-1} - \frac{1}{2^b-1}$$

Which wasn't in the form that I wanted. I needed a remainder.

I also, tried find a recurrence relation, which ends up being:

$$ a_1 = 1, a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 1$$

But, after that, I couldn't really think of anything I could do with it. (Don't even know why I bothered doing this in the first place...)

Then I started thinking in terms of induction:

Maybe let $a$ be an arbitrary natural number, and show that $$(2^a-1, 2^1-1) = (2^a-1,1) = 1 = 2^1 - 1 = 2^{(a,1)} - 1$$

But after the base case I was stumped:

Assume it holds true for all $k$ then if it holds for $k+1$ our claim is true:

$$ (2^a - 1, 2^{k+1} - 1) = (2^a - 1, 2 \cdot 2^k - 1) = ???$$

I don't even think you can use induction quite this way, I've just trying to come up with something. Anyone have any hints? Thank you.

Comment: Much easier to do modular arithmetic. First show that if $d\mid n$ then $2^d-1\mid 2^n-1$. So $2^{(a,b)}-1\mid (2^a-1,2^b-1)$. Then use modular arithmetic to show that any common divisor is a divisor of $2^{(a,b)}-1$, using $ax+by=(a,b)$ for some $x,y$ integers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: The set of notes I'm looking at here (http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~oholtz/H90/integers.pdf) puts "Congruences" after this, so I'm trying to avoid modular arithmetic. (Unless I am mistaken and they are not the same thing, which could very well be the case). But thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat in line with the division idea, you can use the property that $(a,b)=(a-b,b)$ (this is the basis for Euclid's algorithm).  In your case, assuming $a>b$,
\begin{align*}
(2^a-1, 2^b-1) &= ((2^a-1) - 2^{a-b}(2^b-1), 2^b-1)\\
&= (2^{a-b} - 1, 2^b - 1).
\end{align*}
Notice that the exponents have a property analogous to the GCD one.  Just to be clear, if we define $f(a,b) = (2^a-1,2^b-1)$, we can write $f(a,b)=f(a-b,b)$.

This means that if we follow all of the steps to compute the GCD of $a$ and $b$ by Euclid's algorithm, we can carry the steps over to get that $f(a,b)=2^{(a,b)}-1$.

Comment: Ahh, I actually did try something like this, but forgot you could multiply $(2^b - 1)$ by $2^{a-b}$ too... This makes things clearer. So it's kind of like the identity property $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,b)$, mixed with the fact that $\gcd(a,b)$ is (I believe) an isomorphism to $\gcd(2^a - 1, 2^b-1) = 2^{(a,b)} - 1$, $\therefore \gcd(2^a - 1, 2^b-1) = 2^{(a,b)} - 1$?

Comment: Am I correct in my interpretation?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by isomorphism here. But if you mean that steps for computing $(a,b)$ and steps for computing $(2^a-1,2^b-1)$ are in one-to-one correspondence, then I believe you are correct in your interpretation.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Thanks!